# The images do not appear in the generated pdf?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf, dompdf

help, i already tried to change the $chrootValid = true; and also already tried activating the gd in the php.ini code, but even so it does not show the images that I want to integrate
I also tried to use previous versions of dompdf
any idea how to solve the problem?

```html
<?php 

ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>EDITAR ALUMNO</title>
  </head>

<body>
<?php
use Masterminds\HTML5;
require("conectar.php");
$n = $_GET['EDITAR_ID'];
$sele = "SELECT * FROM alumnos, preparatorias where alumnos.opcion_asignada=preparatorias.id_prepa and n='$n'";
$result = $conn->query($sele);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  

$status = "";
if(isset($_POST["enviar"]))
{
$especialidad= $_POST["especialidad"];
$correo= $_POST["correo"];
$telefono= $_POST["telefono"];
$apellido_materno= $_POST["apellido_materno"];
$apellido_paterno= $_POST["apellido_paterno"];
$nombre= $_POST["nombre"];
$folio= $_POST["folio"];
$n= $_POST["n"];

 }
?> 
    <form " id="form_18653" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">                  
    <input id="n" name="n"  class="element text small" type="hidden" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $row['n'];?>"/> 
    <b><p align="center" style="color:red"; >FOLIO= 001 </p></b>
    <img  src="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>baner1.png "img width="1170" height="150">
    
    <p align ="right";>Cancun, Quintana Roo, a ____ de agosto de 2022. </p>
    <p align="">
        ESTIMADO (A) DIRECTOR (A) <br><br>
      PRESENTE. <br><br>
      En el marco de Proceso de asignacion de espacios a nivel media superios (PAEMS), 
      que coordina esta secretaria y deacuerdo a los espacios ofertados en el plantel <b><?php echo $row['subsistema']; ?> <?php echo $row['nombre_plantel']; ?></b>
      que usted dignamente representa, solicito su valioso apoyo para asiganr un espacio al alumno(a) <b><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> <?php echo $row['apellido_paterno']; ?> <?php echo $row['apellido_materno']; ?></b>
      con folio CENEVAL <b><?php echo $row['folio']; ?></b> , en la especialidad de <b><?php echo $row['especialidad']; ?></b>. En este sentido, solicitamos a usted confirmar la entraga de esta tarjeta y la asignacion del espacio 
      solicitando al alumno el mismo dia de su presentacion, a efecto de actualizar y mantener vigentes nuestros regstros. <br><br>

      Sin otro particular, me es grato enviarle un cordial saludo. <br><br>
      <b><p style="color:red"; >Nota: La presente tarjeta tiene una vigencia del dia de expedicion y hasta las 13:00 horas del dia siguente.</p> <br><br></b>
    </p>
    <img img width="1200" height="150" src="baner2.png">
    </form> 

    </body>
  </html>
  <?php 
$html=ob_get_clean();
//echo $html;
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$Dompdf = new Dompdf();

$options = $Dompdf->getOptions();
$options->set(array('isRemoteEnabled' => true));
$Dompdf->setOptions($options);

$Dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$Dompdf->setpaper('letter');

$Dompdf->render();
$Dompdf->stream("registro $row[nombre].pdf", array("attachment"=> true));

?>
```

[enter image description here][1]

help, i already tried to change the $chrootValid = true; and also already tried activating the gd in the php.ini code, but even so it does not show the images that I want to integrate
I also tried to use previous versions of dompdf
any idea how to solve the problem?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bNkr.png